# What is the name of set of input vertices in Steiner tree?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, graph-theory

**The Steiner tree problem**

> Problem definition: Given a weighted undirected graph G(V,E), and a set S subset of V find the Minimum-Cost tree that spans the nodes in S. This problem is known in the literature as the Steiner tree problem. Let M the number of nodes in S, which we will call participants.

**What is the name of  set of input vertices in Steiner tree problem?**

Some call it as *terminal set, participant set, Steiner set....etc.*

So What is the real name of input vertices?

Comment: VtC primarily a matter of opinion, but as long as I'm writing a comment, let me suggest as someone who wrote a paper on Steiner forest that "terminals" is what I'd go with.

Comment: According to Wikipedia : a leaf node, or terminal node is any node that does not have child nodes. So can we use terminal set? The meaning is different now....

Comment: I have never seen "terminal" used to mean "leaf" outside the context of formal languages (and certainly not in any of the contexts usually relevant to Steiner trees).